# Symfony2 how to include a parent formType into another

Tags: forms, symfony, formbuilder

i'm trieng to write a bundle for some fields.
Now i got an class which i can extend.
The class got some fields e.g. Title, Name etc.

Now i want to write a formType which can be extended by another formtype.

Like

```
class newsgroupType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('unusername','text',array(
                'required' => true))
        ->add('unactive','checkbox',array(
                'required' => false));
...
```

The FormType which i want to extend is

```
class mainType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('unurl','text',array(
              'required' => false,
              'disabled' => true))
        ->add('untitle','text',array(
              'required' => false))
...
```

Is there a way to extend the mainType to get all fields from it into my newsgroupType?

Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html) on the Symfony website that gives and example of how to extract common fields into a separate form definition which can then be included into other form definitions.

Create a separate `Form` class that includes the common fields using the builder. You can then configure that form using the `inherit_data` option:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'inherit_data' => true
    ));
}
```

The other forms can then add that form in the builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('foo', new CommonType(), array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Foo'
    ));
}
```

Comment: So great!! You saved my evening! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cRsakaWolf if this is the answer you were seeking then upvote and accept it. There is no need to post your own answer except if it doesn't differ.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should think it differently.

You can use nested form types to do what you want.

For example :

```
class newsgroupType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('main', new MainType())
            ->add('unusername','text',array(
                    'required' => true))
            ->add('unactive','checkbox',array(
                    'required' => false));
...
```

You should also namle your classes the right way, with **CamelCase** *(in my example, MainType instead of mainType)*